# spring cloud stream custom value deserializer does not work

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, debezium

I have this simple spring cloud stream Function

```java
@Configuration
public class ItemProcessor {

    @Bean
    public Serde<Wish> WishSerde(){
        Serde<Wish> wishSerde = DebeziumSerdes.payloadJson(Wish.class);
        wishSerde.configure(Collections.singletonMap("from.field", "after"), false);
        return wishSerde;
    }

    @Bean
    public Serde<Long> KeySerde(){
        final Serde<Long> keySerde = DebeziumSerdes.payloadJson(Long.class);
        keySerde.configure(Collections.emptyMap(), true);
        return keySerde;
    }

    @Bean
    public Function<KStream<Long, Wish>, KStream<Long, Wish>> processItems() {
        return (models) -> models
                .peek((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
    }
}
```

And here is the Wish model

```java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Wish {

    public long wish_id;
    public long user_id_fk;
    public long item_id_fk;
    public long wish_status;

}
```

And the application.yml

```yaml
spring.cloud:
  function.definition: processItems
  stream:
    bindings:
      processItems-in-0:
        destination: source.wish
      processItems-out-0:
        destination: processed.wish
    kafka:
      streams:
        binder:
          brokers: 127.0.0.1:9092
```

I am using configured bean for Serde as described in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.4/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_inbound_deserialization) and using Debezium JsonSerde as described [here](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/integrations/serdes.html) to deserialize objects created by Debezium.

The incoming message is like this:

```
{"wish_id":759}|{"before":null,"after":{"wish_id":759,"user_id_fk":2,"item_id_fk":823,"wish_status":1},"source":{"version":"1.6.0.Final","connector":"mysql","name":"JDP","ts_ms":1635151905000,"snapshot":"false","db":"jdb","sequence":null,"table":"wish","server_id":1,"gtid":null,"file":"mysql-bin.000008","pos":2694699,"row":0,"thread":null,"query":null},"op":"c","ts_ms":1635151886089,"transaction":null}
```

where the key and value are separated by `|`.

I need the content of the `'after'` field to use as data for the `Wish` model and this Serde with this config suppose to do that. But I get the following error at the runtime:

```
Exception in thread "processItems-applicationId-062d6a97-b543-47ea-b938-b1b520a6faa8-StreamThread-1" org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Deserialization exception handler is set to fail upon a deserialization error. If you would rather have the streaming pipeline continue after a deserialization error, please set the default.deserialization.exception.handler appropriately.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:82)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.updateHead(RecordQueue.java:176)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordQueue.addRawRecords(RecordQueue.java:112)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.PartitionGroup.addRawRecords(PartitionGroup.java:185)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.addRecords(StreamTask.java:895)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addRecordsToTasks(TaskManager.java:1008)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollPhase(StreamThread.java:812)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:625)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:564)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:523)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "before" (class ir.jdro.kafkaStream.rdbAggregator.model.Wish), not marked as ignorable (4 known properties: "wish_status", "wish_id", "user_id_fk", "item_id_fk"])
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: ir.jdro.kafkaStream.rdbAggregator.model.Wish["before"])
    at io.debezium.serde.json.JsonSerde$JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonSerde.java:95)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.SourceNode.deserializeValue(SourceNode.java:58)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.RecordDeserializer.deserialize(RecordDeserializer.java:66)
```

Once I set `"unknown.properties.ignored", true` for Serde configuration and prevent application from raising the exception I get the following output result:

```
759|{"wish_id":0,"user_id_fk":0,"item_id_fk":0,"wish_status":0}
```

Which shows the key deserialization works fine but the value deserialization isn't.

I can't find where I am wrong!

Comment: You don't need a serde for this https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/transformations/event-flattening.html

Comment: I think it is related to that particular debezium `Serde`. Do you need to configure anything further? It looks like Spring has successfully inferred the type and passed the correct `Serde` to the Kafka Streams function.

Comment: Hey, relative novice here, but it looks to me like your deserializer is looking for a message that matches the structure of your Wish class, but actually attempting to deserialize a message with a value containing `before`, `after`, and `source` fields. Which obviously doesn't match up. So do you need instead to deserialize to something like the following?
```public class Message {
    public Wish before;
    public Wish after;
    public Source source;
}```
That should help with deserialization, and then access the `after` values in your `processItems` function to get `v.after`.